# How to check feature relevance and representativeness?

Tags: feature-selection

How to check whether features from one domain are relevant in other domain?
How to evaluate whether features are representing that domain?

Comment: This is too vague. Can you give an example?

Comment: What do you understand by domain?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application. For example, if you have a classification problem (It means you have labels for your data), you can classify your data using only one specific feature and check how representative is that specific feature. Or, you can do classification with and without a specific feature and see how much difference a specific feature can make.